# By default, reading which character in the input buffer makes scanf() stop reading a string?

Tags: c, string, input, scanf

When I do not use any scanset or a negated scanset, encountering which character in the buffer will make `scanf()` stop reading data from the buffer (assuming that the character array is large enough)? It seemed as if the answer is a blank because if we enter a multi-worded sentence in the output, then by default `scanf()` stores only the first word but when i run this code:

```
int main(void) {  
    char n[20];
    int status;
    do {
        status = scanf("%[^ ]", n);
        //status = scanf("%s", n);
        printf("%d %s\n", status, n);
    } while (status);
    return 0;
}
```

and enter `hello world` as the input and press the return key, the output is:

```
1 hello
0 hello
```

and when I change the `do`-`while` to:

```
 do {
    //status = scanf("%[^ ]", n);
    status = scanf("%s", n);
    printf("%d %s\n", status, n);
} while (status);
```

I get this as the output (for the same input):

```
1 hello
1 world
```

and the program failed to terminate on its own

Again, for the first `do`-`while`, if I enter `hello` and press enter, I do not get any output and program doesn't terminate (obviously because it read no space). But this is not the case for the second `do`-`while`.

Also it would be great if someone could answer how do I change my code to make it terminate upon pressing the return key, all the while storing one word at a time.

Comment: As the man page will tell you, it normally ignores leading whitespace and stops at the next whitespace (as second example). The first example specifically instructs `scanf` to  treat a space as a terminator: so it remains in the input buffer.

Comment: It is often recommended not to use `scanf` at all, it can get knotty. Using `fgets` and then `sscanf` is easier to manage.

Comment: very good question. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a negated scanset, `scanf()` stops reading when it gets a byte from `stdin` that matches the scanset (a space for your `%[^ ]` format) or when it reaches the end of file.

Note that if it reads a matching byte or the end of file right away, the conversion fails and `scanf()` returns `0` or `EOF` respectively.

You should change your code to avoid passing the `n` array to `printf()` if the conversion failed as it would be uninitialized and the behavior in `printf()` would be undefined.

You should also prevent a potential buffer overflow by passing the maximum number of characters to store into `n` before the null terminator.

Here is a safer version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {  
    char n[20];
    int status;
    while ((status = scanf("%19[^ ]", n)) == 1) {
        printf("%d %s\n", status, n);
    }
    printf("stop with status=%d\n", status);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with the above loop is the second iteration will fail because the space is still pending in `stdin`.

- You can fix this by adding an initial ' ' in the format string to skip initial white space before the conversion: `scanf(" %19[^ ]", n)`, but this would skip other white space such as newlines.
- you should probably stop the `scanf` on newline characters as well
- A stricter solution is to skip the pending spaces after each successful conversion:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(void) {  
      char n[20];
      int status;
      while ((status = scanf("%19[^ \n]", n)) == 1) {
          printf("%d %s\n", status, n);
          scanf("%*[ \n]"); // skip spaces
      }
      printf("stop with status=%d\n", status);
      return 0;
  }
  ```

If you want to exit the loop if the user presses enter on an empty line, you can test for this first and unget the byte if it is not a newline:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {  
    char n[20];
    int c, status;
    for (;;) {
        if ((c = getchar()) == EOF || c == '\n')
            break;
        ungetc(c, stdin);
        if ((status = scanf("%19[^ \n]", n)) == 1) {
            printf("%d %s\n", status, n);
            scanf("%*c"); // skip the space or newline that stopped the scanf
        } else {
            printf("stop with status=%d\n", status);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code works as expected, except for the last word in the input. The last word does not get printed. If i enter some more input after this, something unexpected gets printed. Else, if I just keep on pressing the return key (14 times on my machine), that required word is shown. Also this line `printf("stop with status=%d\n", status);` never gets executed, it seems.

Comment: The problem is in the `scanf()` call: `scanf()` reads input until it gets a space, the end of file or 19 characters have been read.  If you wish for newline to stop the scanf, you must include it in the format string. I updated the answer for this purpose.

Comment: The "stricter solution" benefits with a prior `scanf("%*[ ]");` before the while loop to consume leading spaces.  Else `"  abc def ghi  "` reports nothing.

Comment: @chux: that's true, parsing input with `scanf()` is very tricky.

Answer (score 3):

> By default, reading which character in the input buffer makes scanf() stop reading a string?

There is no default.
When/how `scanf()` stops depends on the *format*.  Reading will also stop when end-of-file is encountered or an input error.

```
// format "%c"
// Reads 1 character, then stops, no special value stops it early.
char ch;
scan("%c", &ch);

// format "%9[^ ]"
// Reads up to 9 non-space characters, then stops.  Even reads a null character.
char buf[10];
scan("%9[^ ]", buf);

// format "%9s"
// Reads and discards leading white-space characters, 
//   then reads/saves up to 9 non-white-space characters, then stops.  
// Even reads a null character.
char buf[10];
scan("%9s", buf);

// format "xyz"
// Reads up to 3 characters that match the pattern "xyz", then stops.  
scan("xyz");
```

Comment: 1. Can u tell more about that last format "xyz"? Like where will the input be stored? Give an example illustrating its use maybe.  2. Also please suggest how to read blank lines with scanf because "%[\n]" doesn't do it.

Comment: 1) The input is not stored.  If input is `"xa"`, the `x` is consumed and the `a` put back for next time.  2) `scanf()` is challenging to use correctly for read _lines_ of input.  Why do you not use `fgets()`?

Comment: Trying to understand scanf() before i move to using fgets(). Thanks.

Comment: @NityeshAgarwal Note that the C has about 8 pages of specification for `scanf()` and `fscanf()`.  `fgets()` use 1/2 page.  Recommend `fgets()` for reading lines and not use `scanf()` at all.  Your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Capturing enter with scanf is difficult. Using `fgets` it is easy to see if a blank line has been entered by checking index [0]. Use sscanf to parse each word. The `%n` specifier will tell you how many characters were used in the scan. That value can be added to the pointer `temp` to parse each word.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char n[256] = { '\0'};
    char word[256] = { '\0'};
    char *temp = NULL;
    int result = 0;
    int chs = 0;

    while ( 1) {
        printf("\nEnter text(enter only to exit)\n");
        fgets ( n, sizeof n, stdin);
        if ( n[0] == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        temp = n;
        while ( 1 == ( result = sscanf ( temp, "%255s%n", word, &chs))) {
            temp += chs;
            printf ( "%s\n", word);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Another approach would be to read each character using `getchar`. Check for a newline to exit, check for whitespace to print each word and check for printable characters to accumulate into each word.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LIMIT 79

int main( void) {
    char n[LIMIT + 1] = { '\0'};
    int at = 0;
    int ch = 0;

    printf ( "type the text and press enter\n");
    while ( ( ch = getchar ( )) != EOF) {
        if ( ch == '\n') {
            if ( at) {
                fputs ( n, stdout);
                fputc ( '\n', stdout);
            }
            at = 0;
            break;
        }
        if ( at >= LIMIT || isspace ( ch)) {
            if ( at) {
                fputs ( n, stdout);
                fputc ( '\n', stdout);
            }
            at = 0;
        }
        if ( isgraph ( ch)) {
            n[at] = ch;
            at++;
            n[at] = '\0';
        }
    }
    if ( at) {
        fputs ( n, stdout);
        fputc ( '\n', stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```